# Careers has trouble with my location

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Stack Overflow Careers insists that I live in »Tubinga«, which appears to be the Italian or Spanish variant of »Tübingen« (where I live). It completely ignores what I put in the »city« field and instead replaces it with the misspelling. Testing appears to show that the city is looked up from the postal code.

Fun things:

- Entering (almost) anything in the city field results in »Tubinga«
- Entering »Tübingen-Hirschau« results in »Hirschau«, so districts seem to be looked up as well. That being said, »Tubinga, Germany« is something most Germans would struggle with to understand what is meant and »Hirschau, Germany« is ambiguous (there is one in Bavaria as well).

I'd rather see the correct spelling of the city, or at the very least, let the user override the automatic city lookup which may be strange or wrong in certain cases.

Comment: Umziehen, Heidelberg soll auch nett sein.

Comment: I just moved and don't really want to do so again in the near future. That being said, from my point of view (or ear) everyone talks strange down here, so Heidelberg or Tübingen doesn't make too much of a difference ;-)

Comment: Yes, the language they speak down there is strange, it's not only your ears.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use the German site when updating your profile:

[http://careers.stackoverflow.com/**de**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de)

The language of the site you're on matters when we geocode your location. So, for instance, "München" becomes "Munich" if you're on the English site.

That being said, "Tübingen" should still be "Tübingen" in English, so this looks like an invalid data record in the geo database which needs to be fixed.

Comment: It now uses »Gemeinde Tubingen« (sic), where I can't really decide whether it's worse or just equally bad. (1) People usually give their locations in cities/towns, not in larger administrative divisions such as Gemeinden; (2) the umlaut is missing, which is strange if that is supposed to be the German variant of that location.

Comment: Try leaving "Bundesland" and "PLZ" empty, just enter Stadt = "Tübingen".

Comment: Re your now deleted comment: This makes little sense. You're completely ignoring what I enter in the *city* field and just use whatever some database returns for the postal code. You're blindly using the result in either case (which happens to be wrong in both instances). So you could just show whatever you're pulling from the database to the employer if they are in a certain country, but the actual location should probably remain in the candidate's language, I guess.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work, but only from the German site again (which still reads a bit weird in some places by the way). So I now have to be careful never to touch that field again, lest I want the wrong data to reappear?

Comment: @Joey we're actually using all three fields "city", "state/province", and "zip/postal" to geocode your location. Sometimes, the geocoding service returns something which is different from the user input. For example, user enters "NY" which then gets updated to "New York".

Comment: @Joey your location should now remain unchanged until you update it again. Feel free to let us know where the German site reads a bit weird btw, localization is a tricky issue and we always welcome feedback.

Comment: As an aside, it also used to change Helsinki to Helsingfors, which is the Swedish variant of the capital of Finland (although this seems to have been fixed now).